# How to generate provisioning profiles suitable for offline debug via fastlane

Tags: fastlane, apple-developer, fastlane-match

Regularly testing and debugging on unstable network connection is critical for the project I work on. But some time ago I've run into a problem when needed to debug my app behaviour on unstable network. Since then I haven't find any solid solution.

It appeared that from some moment you can use Xcode debugger only when connected to internet by default. And that is forced by provisioning profile, as shown on next screenshot from Apple Developer portal:

[image]

To continue debug session when phone goes offline, you need the provisioning profile to be configured for offline support.

If I put this flag manually on the portal and download the profile, everything works. The problem is that I use fastlane for provisioning profiles management. Changing anything on the developer portal by hand goes against the nature of using fastlane for profiles management. And moreover profiles for offline-mode are valid only for 7 days. Going to portal every week and regenerating each development profile (we have a lot) does not sound as a good idea. But I can't see any options in fastlane/match how to manage that flag from lane configuration.